# SSIS Data Manipulation for Column

Tags: ssis

I have excel file with three columns i.e A, B, C.
I want to import these three columns into DB table A,B,C.
Below is the Mapings.

```
Excel A  --> DB Table A
Excel B  --> DB Table B
Excel C  --> DB Table C
```

I want to import C column by manipulating data i.e C*50 while importing it to databse.

can anyone please suggest me how to do data manipulation part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Derived Column component between the Source and Destination. Either replace, or create a new column with different name with the value as C * 50. Then connect the Derived Column output and map the new computed column to column C in the Destination.